# Prevent chrome from auto-hiding bookmark bar on google search

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

I am using Chrome 28.0.1500.20 beta on OSX 10.7.
In this version, when you perform a google search using the address bar the bookmarks bar disappears. Toggling "always show bookmarks bar" does not restore the bookmark (see screenshot below).

I want to always show the bookmark bar. In particular, I often use a bookmarklet that converts a current google search into a Google Scholar search.

**Is there a way to always show the bookmark bar even when performing a Google search in Chrome?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling "Action box" in your chrome://flags should help, at least it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the favorites icon toolbar no longer disappeared when I changed some settings in the chrome://flags/ page.  Unfortunately I changed a number of settings and I do not know exactly which one effected the favorite icon bar but I can say that before I made the changes I was having the exact same issue with my favorite icon bar disappearing and now that does not happen.

I should note that I am using Win 7 SP1

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this might be a bug, but it appears to be a feature. I haven't found any way to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's called presentation mode:

Go to the OS X menu bar while still in Chrome and click *View » Exit Presentation Mode*. Tis might kick you off full screen, no worries: *View » Enter Full Screen*.